# Как следить за перемещением курсора на определенное количество пикселей(100)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Задача: сделать так, чтобы выводился символ, каждый раз, когда курсор перемещается на более чем 100 пикселей. Как это сделать? Попробовал такой вариант:

```
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    POINT lpPointCursor;
    GetCursorPos(&lpPointCursor);
switch (message)
    {
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        POINT lpPointMove;
        lpPointMove.x = LOWORD(lParam);
        lpPointMove.y = HIWORD(lParam);
        if (abs(lpPointCursor.x - lpPointMove.x) >= 100 || abs(lpPointCursor.y - lpPointMove.y) >= 100) {
            hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            TextOut(hdc, lpPointMove.x, lpPointMove.y, "a", 1);
        }
        break;
}
```

Однако он не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам надо запоминать старое положение курсора где-то выше функции с обработчиками событий ну или использовать статические данные

```
    POINT lpPointMove;
    static POINT lpOldPointMove = {0, 0};

    lpPointMove.x = LOWORD(lParam);
    lpPointMove.y = HIWORD(lParam);
    if (abs(lpOldPointMove.x - lpPointMove.x) >= 100 || abs(lpOldPointMove.y - lpPointMove.y) >= 100) {
        hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        TextOut(hdc, lpPointMove.x, lpPointMove.y, "a", 1);
    }

    lpOldPointMove = lpPointMove;

    break;
```

**P.S.**

кстати если вам надо расстояние все таки от некоторой точки, то не стоит измерять только по оси x и по оси y, вам нужно именно расстояние от точки до точки, т.е.

```
sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y1) * (y1 - y2)) < 100
```

ну или чтобы не тратить время на корень и не терять точности просто работать с квадратами

```
(x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y1) * (y1 - y2) < 100 * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zhihar
У меня `lpOldPointMove` в коде это:
 `POINT lpPointCursor;`
`GetCursorPos(&lpPointCursor);`
Однако я еще вынес определение `lpPointMove` за пределы кейса, но это не помогает. Сейчас код выглядит примерно так:

```
lpPointMove.x = LOWORD(lParam);
lpPointMove.y = HIWORD(lParam);
if (pow((lpPointCursor.x - lpPointMove.x), 2) + pow((lpPointCursor.y - lpPointMove.y), 2) > 100 * 100) { 
hdc = GetDC(hWnd); 
TextOut(hdc, lpPointMove.x, lpPointMove.y, "a", 1);
}
lpPointCursor = lpPointMove;
break;
```